# extract clusters / sets of nodes from an undirected graph

Tags: matrix, graph, cluster-computing, connected-components

**Description**

I would like to identify and obtain n-sized clusters in form of groups of nodes from an undirected graph dataset (optimally in Python). Currently I am stuck in a sphere way outside of my comfort and knowledge zone so i thought it may be worth a try reaching out to interested people here.

A cluster here is characterized as a set of nodes being all interconnected through an (non-directional) edge. For simplification reasons all edge weights can be considered with weight = 1. Also there are no further information stored neither within nodes or edges.

Below figure illustrates data structure and dependencies

Graph scheme

[image: Graph scheme]

For this I am striving to find a solution that automatically detects the sets of nodes that are entirely interconnected as illustrated below:

Expected Cluster Results

[image: Expected Cluster Results]

Where the cluster size should be recognized dynamically and always consider the maximum number of interconnected nodes (e.g. n1 and n2 are not considered as own cluster as n3 has a connection with both of them).

**Approaches**

I tried solving this through the concept of strongly connected components but it does not seem to deliver the desired output as the connection between all nodes is not directional.
I have tried approaching this problem also in matrix form as shown below:

Graph as matrix

[image: Graph as matrix]

But I am failing at an elegant solution that does not incorporate a not-scalable approach using nested loops iterating through the indices.

Does anyone have an idea about how to approach this or optimally even worked on this with a sharable solution I could orientate on? 
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct naming of your **cluster** is [complete subgraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph). Your problem is known as [clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem). One of the best graph processing libraries for Python - networkx - has several algorithms for solving this problem:
[networkx cliques](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/algorithms.clique.html)

Your problem can be solved by this function: [networkx.algorithms.clique.enumerate_all_cliques](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.enumerate_all_cliques.html#networkx.algorithms.clique.enumerate_all_cliques)

You should convert your graph into networkx format and use these algorithms to find it.

Comment: Just thank you so much! This is probably the most on-point, informative and helpful answer i could have imagined :)